# Custom Font Embedding DOES NOT WORK Cross-Browser

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser, embedding

I have have "Gulim", a custom font, embedded into my website at mangodownload.com (you can see it on the homepage, if you see Arial, it does not work on your browser.)

Unfortunately, this font does NOT work on many browsers.

Here is my CSS for the font:

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: "Gulim";
    src: url("/style/fonts/Gulim.ttf");
    src: local("Gulim"), url("/style/fonts/Gulim.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

Any ideas on achieving cross-browser support for ALL browsers?

**PLEASE NOTE:** I have tried converting the font, and tried FontSquirrel. I keep receiving the same message; 'font size too large'. My *gulim.ttf* file is 10mb.

Comment: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface

Comment: What's a `.tff` font?  The `.ttf` extension is the more normal one for TrueType.

Comment: And the URL to the page is...?

Comment: SO deleted my link. I'll edit it.
@robertc the .tff was a mistake on my part, sorry. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'yourfunkyfont';
    src: url('fonts/yourfunkyfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/yourfunkyfont.svg') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/yourfunkyfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('fonts/yourfunkyfont.woff') format('woff'),
      url('fonts/yourfunkyfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('fonts/yourfunkyfont.svg#yourfunkyfont') format('svg');
}
```

this will work only if you add the following MIME-types in your IIS (other webserver):

```
.woff - application/x-font-woff
.svg - application/x-font-woff
```

Comment: I know this, but how do I convert my font to .woff and .svg?

Comment: @HugoCornellier, convert your font with a [font convertor](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=font+conversion).

Comment: They all say my font's filesize is too big. Any way to size down the file, then convert it? Unfortunately, the file is >10mb.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this cross-browser unless you can get your font in the various formats required by various browsers. The [CSS to use](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax) is as follows:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
     url('myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
     url('myfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
     url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```

As you can see, you need the font in `eot`, `woff`, `ttf` and `svg` formats.

Comment: What is the easiest way to achieve these conversions, without using FontSquirrel?

Comment: I don't know, but it [can't be difficult to find out](https://www.google.com/search?q=font+converter).

Comment: They all say my font's filesize is too big. Any way to size down the file, then convert it? Unfortunately, the file is >10mb.

Comment: @HugoCornellier You could try something like [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/).